# How to filter complex JSON using jq toolset and regular expressions into new JSON array of objects

Tags: json, jq

> First ~ *Thanks* for taking the time to read this. If any further
>   information or restatements are needed please comment so that I can improve
>   the question. I am new to **jq** and appreciate any assistance provided.
>   If there is any confusion in the topic it is due to my lack of
>   experience with the **jq** tool. This seems fairly complex so even a partial 
>   answer is welcome.

**Background**

I have some JSON objects within a series of JSON arrays (sample at bottom). The objects have a number of elements but only the values associated with the "data" key are of interest to me. I want to output a single array of JSON objects where the values are translated into key/value pairs based on some regular expression rules.

I want to essentially combine multiple "data" values to form a key phrase (and then a value-phrase) which I need to output as the array of target objects. I believe I should be able to use a regular expression or a set of known text (for the key-phrase) to compile the text into a single key or value.

**Current Logic**

*Using: jq-1.5, Mac OS 10.12.6, Bash terminal*

Some things I have examined are by looking at the (:) colon in the value field (it indicates the end of a key-phrase). So for example, below represents the key "Company Address":

```
"data":"Company ",
...
"data": "Address:"
...
{
    "top": 333,
    "left": 520,
    "width": 66,
    "height": 15,
    "font": 5,
    "data":"123 Main St. "
...
"data":"Smallville "
...
"data":"KS "
...
"data":"606101"
```

In this case, the colon in the value indicates that the next value attached to the following useful "data" key is the beginning of an address.

A space trailing the value indicates that the next data value found is a continuation of the key phrase or the value phrase I am attempting to combine into a new JSON object.

I have a set of values that I can use to delimit a new JSON object. Essentially the following example would allow me to create a key "Company Name":

```
...
"data":"Company "
...
"data":"Name"
```

(note that this entry does not have a colon but the pattern will be the start of each new JSON object to be generated)

**Notes**

I can determine when the end of a key or value is reached depending on whether or not it's value ends with a space. (if there is no space then I consider the value to be the end of the value phrase and begin capturing the next key phrase).

**Things I've tried**

Any assistance with translating this logic into one or more useful jq filter(s) would be greatly appreciated. I've taken a look at the [JQ Cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#filter-objects-based-on-the-contents-of-a-key), the [JQ Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), this [article](http://www.compciv.org/recipes/cli/jq-for-parsing-json/), examined other [SO questions on jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jq), and made an evaluation of an alternate tool ([underscore_cli](https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli)). I am new to jq and my naive expressions keep failing...

> I've tried some simple tests to attempt to select values of interest.
>   (I am not successfully able to walk the json tree to get to the
>   information under the text array. Another wrinkle is that I have
>   multiple text arrays. Is it possible to have the same algorithm
>   performed on each array of objects?)

```
jq -s '.[]  | select(.data | contains(":"))'
```

> jq: error (at :0): Cannot index array with string "data"

**Sample**

A sample of the header JSON

```
[
  {
    "number": 1,
    "pages": 254,
    "height": 1263,
    "width": 892,
    "fonts": [
      {
        "fontspec": "0",
        "size": "-1",
        "family": "Times",
        "color": "#ffffff"
      },
      {
        "fontspec": "1",
        "size": "31",
        "family": "Times",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      {
        "fontspec": "2",
        "size": "16",
        "family": "Helvetica",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      {
        "fontspec": "3",
        "size": "13",
        "family": "Times",
        "color": "#237db8"
      },
      {
        "fontspec": "4",
        "size": "17",
        "family": "Times",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      {
        "fontspec": "5",
        "size": "13",
        "family": "Times",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      {
        "fontspec": "6",
        "size": "8",
        "family": "Times",
        "color": "#9f97a7"
      },
      {
        "fontspec": "7",
        "size": "10",
        "family": "Times",
        "color": "#9f97a7"
      }
    ],
    "text": [
      {
        "top": 83,
        "left": 60,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 1,
        "font": 0,
        "data": " "
      },
      {
        "top": 333,
        "left": 68,
        "width": 68,
        "height": 15,
        "font": 5,
        "data": "Company "
      },
      {
        "top": 333,
        "left": 135,
        "width": 40,
        "height": 15,
        "font": 5,
        "data": "Name"
      },
      ...(more of these objects with data)
     ]
    ]
```

> I am looking to output a JSON array of objects whose keys are composed
>   of known strings (patterns) for the key/value pair bound by a colon
>   (:) indicating the end of a key-phrase and whose next data-value would
>   be the start of the value-phrase. The presence of a trailing space
>   indicates that the data-value should be appended as part of the
>   value-phrase until the trailing space no longer appears in the
>   data-value. At that point the next data-value represents the start of
>   another key-phrase.

### UPDATE #1:

> The answers below are very helpful. I've gone back to the jq manual
>   and incorporated the advice below. I am getting a string but unable to
>   separate out the set of data tags into a single string.

```
.[].text |  tostring
```

> However, I am seeing the JSON being escaped and the other tags showing
>   up in the string `top, left, right` (along with their values). I'd
>   like to have the tokens associated only with the data key as a string.
>   Then run the regular expressions over that string to parse out a set
>   of JSON objects where the keys and values can be defined.

Comment: Please provide a small but complete sample of both valid input and the expected output.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @peak All of the data tags in my JSON arrays have tokens that represent both the keys and the values that I want to capture as a set of JSON objects. I'd like to be able to use any given phrase and when a matching set of consecutive tokens are found; use the next token as the value to the key/value pair.

Comment: Please see stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

So from what I could tell what you're trying to do, you're trying to get all the `"data"` elements and concatenating them into a single string.

Should be simple enough to do:

```
[.. | .data? | select(. != null) | tostring] | join("")
```

There's not enough example data to know where the start of one "grouping" of data begins and ends.  But assuming every item in the root array is a single phrase, select each item first before performing the search (or map them):

```
map([.. | .data? | select(. != null) | tostring] | join(""))
```

If ultimately you'd want to parse the data bits to a json object, it's not too far off:

```
map(
    [.. | .data? | select(. != null) | tostring]
        | join("")
        | split(":") as [$key,$value]
        | {$key,$value}
) | from_entries
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've successfully created a string using `.[].text | tostring`. Since all of my data tags contain both keys and values. Is there a way to take any given phrase, search the tokens for a match and use the next token as the value. In some cases, I might want to use regular expressions to determine both the keys and values as well... This is getting me quite close, just unsure how to apply pcre to the output. Also, I'm getting 4 different strings for my output and I'd like my logic to operate over all of them.

Comment: Please show us the inputs you're dealing with now and what you want from it exactly. It's hard to gauge whether or not we can provide a usable solution if there is no clear starting point and ending point. All we can make is best guesses and what you're probably seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using jq [Streaming](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Streaming) for this.  With your sample data the following filter picks out the paths to the "data" attributes:

```
  tostream
| select(length==2) as [$p,$v]
| select($p[-1]=="data")
| [$p,$v]
```

If this is in `filter.jq` and your sample data is in `data.json` the command

```
$ jq -Mc -f filter.jq data.json
```

produces

```
[[0,"text",0,"data"]," "]
[[0,"text",1,"data"],"Company "]
[[0,"text",2,"data"],"Name"]
```

From this you can see your data has information in the paths `.[0].text[0].data`, `.[0].text[1].data` and `.[0].text[2].data`.

You can build on this using [reduce](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce) to collect the values into groups based on the presence of the trailing space.  With your data the following filter

```
reduce (
    tostream
  | select(length==2) as [$p,$v]
  | select($p[-1]=="data")
) as [$p,$v] (
    [""]
  ; .[-1] += $v
  | if $v|endswith(" ")|not then . += [""] else . end
)
| map(select(. != ""))
```

produces

```
[" Company Name"]
```

This example only groups data into a list.  You can use a more sophisticated reduce if you need.

Here is a [**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##pZHBToNAEIbvPMW44QCxNC2Upmo4efcFCIe1TAsGdlcYWo346uIuRYuKFz0Q9v/4ZvZPeHjsYgvgRT8ATDTlPVbsGpazE1B8j7XOfrgaSIb5PiOj@OtgYMc8pUyjzZU/EMIn48R9@lh/@iKVMYfRHhW4M/J6MWIfK8fsfPUI7qSgb17KiWvEgA3sdfZbjyCYKrKZKPIFnpuEP6uEE1VuZam4eP5ro2UQTlRaLf5T6Y6X@FmnfyeWOSVW21WYNlsEp8cka6qQlzq0UGOBW3IKFHvKosh3gdcQ22pmH5KxYKvYWyZRdLrOtcbesDdmzIzcwNyocBmBfehX5Dt9alGk9TGnzNH/0W2FJKAMBcyNaEYBixp11J7lWi2UXDnD5XO4iIAx1@26N6kol6LuPE80ReHlQjWkQ8WPnmxIh3c) link you can experiment with.

To take this further let's use the following sample data:

```
[
    { "data":"Company " },
    { "data": "Address:" },
    { "data":"123 Main St. " },
    { "data":"Smallville " },
    { "data":"KS " },
    { "data":"606101" }
]
```

The filter as is will generate

```
["Company Address:","123 Main St. Smallville KS 606101"]
```

To convert that into an object you could add another reduce.  For example this filter

```
  reduce (
      tostream
    | select(length==2) as [$p,$v]
    | select($p[-1]=="data")
  ) as [$p,$v] (
      [""]
    ; .[-1] += $v
    | if $v|endswith(" ")|not then . += [""] else . end
  )
| map(select(. != ""))
| reduce .[] as $e (
    {k:"", o:{}}
  ; if $e|endswith(":") then .k = $e[:-1] else .o[.k] += $e end
  )
| .o
```

produces

```
{"Company Address":"123 Main St. Smallville KS 606101"}
```

One last thing: at this point the filter is getting pretty large so it would make sense to refactor a bit and break it down into [functions](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#DefiningFunctions) so that it's easier to manage and extend.  e.g.

```
  def extract:
    [   tostream
      | select(length==2) as [$p,$v]     # collect values for
      | select($p[-1]=="data")           # paths to "data"
      | $v                               # in an array
    ]
  ;

  def gather:
    reduce .[] as $v (
        [""]                             # state: list of grouped values
      ; .[-1] += $v                      # add value to last group
      | if $v|endswith(" ")|not          # if the value ended with " "
        then . += [""]                   # form a new group
        else .
        end
    )
    | map(select(. != ""))               # produce final result
  ;

  def combine:
      reduce .[] as $e (
        {k:"", o:{}}                     # k: current key o: combined object
      ; if $e|endswith(":")              # if value ends with a ":"
        then .k = $e[:-1]                #   use it as a new current key
        else .o[.k] += $e                # otherwise add to current key's value
        end
      )
    | .o                                 # produce the final object
  ;

    extract                              # extract "data" values
  | gather                               # gather into groups
  | combine                              # combine into an object
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing me leaps and bounds from where I've been, I really appreciate the effort. Any tips on how to group this into the desired array of JSON objects? I'm also very interested in whether I can use regular expressions to cherry pick different data-values to use.

Comment: I've added an extra reduce to the end showing one approach.

Comment: jq provides support for [regular expressions](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE).